# exec sp_execute followed by a number

Tags: sql, sql-server

When using Microsoft SQL Profiler and you see `exec sp_execute` followed by a number and some arguments (e.g.)

```sql
exec sp_execute 38,@maxChangeTrackingNumberPublishedApplication=7400,@maxChangeTrackingNumberInstalledApplication=7400
```

What does the number after `sp_execute` indicate (38 in this case)? How do I determine what SQL that is executing?

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) says:

> *handle*
> Is the handle value returned by sp_prepare. handle is a required parameter that calls for int input value.

I can see no sign of sp_prepare in my Profiler Trace?

Is there an SQL command to list out all the prepared SQL that sp_execute may be running?

Comment: The number is the handle. Check for other system API proc calls before sp_execute that return handles. Note you'll need to capture all calls on the session since the connection was established. I don't believe there's a way to get handles and the associated SQL statements besides a trace.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is any DMV that exposes this if you start the trace after `sp_prepare` has already been run https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e6624ec5-6fe0-4187-9cb7-13f74f0cb410/where-can-i-find-prepared-sql-statements-spprepare-in-the-system-tablesviews?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: `sp_prepare` is not a normal procedure, it's triggered by `ID=11` TDS packet.

Comment: This returns plan_handle and SQL:_
select sql_handle,
(SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(s2.text,statement_start_offset / 2+1 ,
((CASE WHEN statement_end_offset = -1
  THEN (LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),s2.text)) * 2)
  ELSE statement_end_offset
  END)  - statement_start_offset) / 2+1)) AS sql_statement
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s2

Comment: ... but how do you get from varbinary plan_handle to the decimal number that appears in the sp_execute syntax?